# Nginx Mod Rewrite - Rewrite *.png to *.php

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite, pictures

I am having an issue with Nginx Rewrites

Currently my rule is as seen below

rewrite ^/i/(.*?)$ /i/$1.php last;

Basically what I want to do is redirect all .png files to .php within the /i directory. However, it seems that the $ has to be at the end so that I can not do

rewrite ^/i/(.*?)$.png /i/$1.php last;

Does anyone have any solutions?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Please post the entire `server` block of your nginx configuration.

Comment: Here we go

http://pastebin.com/gSHqtXyi

Answer (score 4):

Requests for .png files are being handled by your `location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$`.  Just stop that from handling png files and add a new location that only handles them:

```
server {
  location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    # the same stuff you already had in here
  }

  location ~* ^(?<basename>.*)\.png$ {
    rewrite ^ $basename.php last;
  }

  # your other locations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now I see the problem.

Your rewrite rule looks like this:

```
rewrite ^/i/(.*?)$ /i/$1.php last;
```

So this would rewrite `/i/cute.png` to `/i/cute.png.php`. It probably doesn't exist.

You said you simply wanted to *change* `.png` to `.php`, so try something like this:

```
rewrite ^/i/(.*?).png$ /i/$1.php last;
```

Comment: Nope :( Still not working :@